# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement

Tags: php, sql

**Consulta:**

```
    static public function contarAccesorios(){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT count(idaccesorio) FROM accesorios;";
        $registro = $ejecucion->query($sql);
        return $registro;
    }
```

**¿Por qué me da el siguiente error?**

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string
```

**Prueba:**

```
echo BD::contarAccesorios();
```

Comment: Si esperas una sola fila, puedes usar **[`fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)** o `fetchAll()`, de ese modo puedes acceder al valor directamente, sin tener que usar un bucle: `return $registro->fetchColumn();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes hacer un return del resultado de la consulta `PDOStatement`. Tienes que leer el resultado e ir mostrándolo:

```
if ($registro->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $registro->fetch_assoc()) {
        //echo...;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

**EDITO:** Si sólo devuelve un número, como es el caso, utiliza:

```
$contador = $registro->fetch();
```

Con varios registros podrías especificar el que quieres:

```
$primero = $contador[0];
```

Comment: Desde el SQL del PHPmyadmin, si ejecuto la consulta me da un resultado (un número, no es un array que deba ir recorriéndolo). ¿Aún así debo leerlo e ir mostrándolo?

Comment: `$ejecucion->query($sql);` devuelve un objeto `PDOStatement`. Sea un registro o varios, no es posible hacerle un return de ese modo.

Comment: ¿Entonces como retorno el resultado para guardarlo en otro fichero en una variable $contador?

Comment: Edito la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

por lo que veo preparaste la query pero no la ejecutaste

```
$pdo = self::Conexion(); // Asumiendo que te devuelve una conexion PDO.
$sql = "SELECT count(idaccesorio) FROM accesorios;";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$resultado = $stmt->fetchall(); 
var_dump($resultado);
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: -1 porque tu respuesta desorienta. Te pregunto: ¿por qué hay que **preparar** esa consulta? Si observas el código, la consulta no ha sido preparada en ningún momento, y no lo ha sido porque efectivamente, este tipo de consultas no se preparan.

Comment: No me parece que la respuesta desoriente. A fines practico y para mantener una coherencia en el desarrollo es una buena solución. Y si todavía tienes dudas también deje la documentación como fuente...
Saludos.

Comment: ¿Consideras una buena solución *lavar una ropa que está limpia*? ¿Cómo justificas a nivel ecológico y económico el desperdicio de detergente, de electricidad, de agua, de desgaste de la lavadora y de la ropa misma? Te pongo un ejemplo de la vida real para que entiendas que no tiene ningún sentido preparar algo que **ya está preparado**. Si la comida está ya cocinada, ¿por qué me dices que hay que cocinarla de nuevo?

Comment: Entonces te pido que me brindes un poco de claridad a mi visión brindado alguna fuente para entender mejor.
PD: no hace falta una actitud tan engreída y peleadora.

Comment: Si lees el Manual de PHP, verás que, cuando la consulta se va a ejecutar **una sola vez**, y no maneja datos provenientes de otras fuentes, lo recomendable es usar [`query`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.query.php). Las consultas preparadas son para optimizar le ejecución de consultas que ocurrirán **varias veces** o para **proteger contra la Inyección SQL**. Ver al respecto lo que dice el Manual sobre [`prepare`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) y sobre [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php). Perdona si te sentiste ofendido, no era mi intención.

Comment: Si aún te quedan dudas, puedes plantear una pregunta al respecto. Eso permitirá que otros expertos respondan con más argumentos y documentación.